# Google Maps Android API v2 only shows tiles when I touch the screen

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

**Problem**

When application starts, it shows a white Google Map (I can see the Google logo), and even waiting for minutes with a good internet connection it doesn't load tiles.

However, if I touch the screen, tiles start appearing (One tile per touch).

I tested with 3 physical phones, getting the same results.

**MapActivity**

```
public class MapActivity extends Activity {

    private MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap gmap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        gmap = mMapView.getMap();
        gmap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        gmap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        gmap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
        gmap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
        gmap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

        MapsInitializer.initialize(mMapView.getContext());
    }

}
```

**Layout**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout">
    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Manifiest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.nst.lazzus" >

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.nst.lazzus.MapActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="MY_API_KEY"/>
</application>
```

**Log**

```
03-01 13:37:53.627  18306-18306/com.nst.lazzus I/x﹕ Making Creator dynamically
03-01 13:37:53.631  18306-18306/com.nst.lazzus W/ResourcesManager﹕ Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
03-01 13:37:53.632  18306-18306/com.nst.lazzus W/ResourcesManager﹕ Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
03-01 13:37:53.648  18306-18306/com.nst.lazzus I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Google Play services client version: 6587000
03-01 13:37:53.656  18306-18306/com.nst.lazzus I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Google Play services package version: 6776438
03-01 13:37:54.095  18306-18321/com.nst.lazzus W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 5.532ms
03-01 13:37:54.108  18306-18321/com.nst.lazzus I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 50758(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 15(1627KB) LOS objects, 14% free, 21MB/25MB, paused 7.115ms total 52.092ms
03-01 13:37:54.222  18306-18367/com.nst.lazzus D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
03-01 13:37:54.228  18306-18306/com.nst.lazzus D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
03-01 13:37:54.278  18306-18367/com.nst.lazzus I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/24/14, 167c270, I68fa98814b
03-01 13:37:54.279  18306-18367/com.nst.lazzus I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-01 13:37:54.292  18306-18367/com.nst.lazzus D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use a `Fragment android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"` instead?

Comment: Please sign the application. and use the signed apk to test

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that you forward calls to these methods on the `MapView` from the corresponding methods of your `Activity`:

```
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
onDestroy()
onLowMemory()
onPause()
onResume()
onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
```

The only method I can see that you are forwarding now is `onCreate`.

However, a more convenient solution would be to use `MapFragment` or `SupportMapFragment`.

Comment: Why is this the fix?

Comment: @Jessedegans The lifecycle methods has to be called on the MapView for it to be able to function properly. But as stated, there are better and more convenient ways.

Answer (score 2):

Use Frame layout I have done...try this

xml code

```html
<FrameLayout
   android:id="@+id/mapView"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_below="@+id/slider" >
</FrameLayout>
```

java code in onCreate

```html
 MapFragment fragment = new MapFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction =getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.mapView, fragment).commit();
```

Manifest.xml
insert this both tag inside  tag.

```html
<meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
     android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
     android:value="YOUR GOOGLE MAP KEY" />
```

Answer (score 1):

`getMap()` method is deprecated. Use `getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback)` instead. The callback method provides you with a GoogleMap instance guaranteed to be non-null and ready to be used.

Comment: Same behaviour with getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Google maps have problems with drawing. Try to modify your layout adding an overlay view -- this solved my similar problem

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout">
    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: It doesn't work either. I also tried to replace FrameLayout with a LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

`MapView` is for `Google Maps Android API v1`, for `Google Maps Android API v2`, you should use `MapFragment` instead. However you still can use `MapView` in `Map API V2`, but need:

> Users of this class must forward all the activity life cycle methods - such as onCreate(), onDestroy(), onResume(), and onPause() - to the corresponding methods in the MapView class.

Besides, call `mMapView.onResume();` after `mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` make map show quick.

Finally you must initialize map in your `onCreate(...)` by:

```
MapsInitializer.initialize(this);
```